# How to solve this linear Cauchy Problem

Tags: parabolic-pde, linear-pde, cauchy-problem

within my thesis, I am struggeling with the following PDE:

$u_t+a(x,y)u_{xx}+b(x,y)u_{xy}+c(x,y)u_{yy}+d(x,y)u_{x}+e(x,y)u_{y}+f(x,y)u=0$
$u(T,x,y)=1,$

where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are polynomials and the domain is the set $\{(t,x,y):t\in[0,T],x+y=1,x\geq0,y\geq0\}$.

I showed, however, that there exists a unique solution and I would like to have this solution explicitly, either via Maple/Matlab or *by hand*. My problem hereby is that this PDE is not in the right form for Matlab, Maple is not able to solve it ([here my post in mapleprime](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/225223-Maple-Doesnt-Solve-My-PDE-With-Pdsolve-Why?reply=reply)) and I don't know how to handle this by hand since I never discretized a PDE in two spatial variables. Besides that, substituting $x$ by $1-y$ also does not work since there are mixed derivatives.

Do you have any advice for me? I would be so grateful.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,

utcyp

Comment: do you have some additional constraints on the boundary of your triangle? You could use a uniform grid and do some finite differences.

Comment: Hey user35593, thanks for your reply.  I only have these constraints. Actually, my domain should be a line segment. Therefore, I guess that it is not possible to discretize it.

Comment: Ok I didnt see that. But then how do you define the derivative by x and/or y if your function is only defined on the x+y=1 line? How did you prove existence and uniqueness? For me it seems the problem is not well-posed.

Comment: Hey, in order to show the existence and uniqueness I used Thm. 10 of Ch. 2.9 from [Krylov](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540709138) in a $n$-dimensional space where I don't get these difficulties since I then have a open set (the $n$-dimensional probability simplex). Hence, the problem should be well-posted in more dimensions, isn't it?

Comment: The statements about uniqueness seems to be incorrect. As an example, make a change of variables (x,y): turn on $\pi/4$. The equation will have the same form. Put $a\equiv=-1$, $b\equiv c\equiv\ldots0$. Then the solution of the heat is not unique since no conditions on the segment's boundary are posed.